# Print all columns and rows of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

As shown in the screenshot a 2D `numpy` array is truncated for printing purposes. I would like to have all elements displayed. Is there an option setting to enable that behavior?

[image]

Comment: numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan) maybe you can try it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) on print options. Specifically:

> threshold : int, optional
>
> Total number of array elements which trigger summarization rather than full repr (default 1000).

So setting `threshold` to `np.inf` means it is never summarized.

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
```