# How to print all colounm elements from a .dat file for large number of data(~10,000)

Tags: arrays, numpy, large-data

Let's say I have a .dat file and try to print its first column using this code:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('d.dat', dtype='str')
a=data[:, 1]
print(a)
```

Now, when number of data is around 500, it prints all data.
But for 5,000 numbers of data, it prints like this:

```
a=['1' '2' '3' .......'9' '10']
```

Now my question is how to print for large numbers of data like this:

```
a=['1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10']
```

Comment: `for i in a: print(i, sep=' ')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print all columns and rows of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603888/print-all-columns-and-rows-of-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1):

Solution from post:
[Print all columns and rows of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603888/print-all-columns-and-rows-of-a-numpy-array):

> See [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) on print options. Specifically:
>
> > threshold : int,
> > optional
> >
> > Total number of array elements which trigger summarization rather than
> > full repr (default 1000).
>
> So setting threshold to np.inf means it is
> never summarized.   `np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)`

Comment: Yeah, it's worked. And thanks. It is basically increased the bits.