# How to see the parts being simplified in .npz files?

Tags: python, numpy, artificial-intelligence

I am doing a SMILES Embedding on one of my files. After the embedding, it gives me a .npz file.
When I was trying to view the content inside the .npz file, I uses the code

```
import numpy as np
np_data=np.load('covid_cure_pure_conanical.npz')
for k in np_data:
    print(k)
    print(np_data[k])
```

Then, it gives me the data that got simplified as ... inside the array.
Are there any ways to see the complete set? If not, are there anyways for me to change the npz file into files like .csv or .txt?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `np_data[k]` will be a numpy array.  Large arrays (by default >1000 elements) are displayed in summary form.  Before trying to look at whole arrays, I'd suggest displaying summary information like `shape` and `dtype`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, what I am really trying to achieve is to get the actual values inside. (FYI, the np.shape only shows (0,99) and np.dtype says "Cannot interpret '<numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile object at 0x7fcf887ca2b0>' as a data type")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603888/print-all-columns-and-rows-of-a-numpy-array?r=SearchResults&s=5|47.5910